# Code completion in TextWrangler

Tags: macos, bbedit

I've been looking for it, but I can't seem a way to enable it. Is there a way to enable code completion in TextWrangler?

I need it for C/C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TextWrangler does not natively support code completion BUT because it is so extensively 
AppleScript-able, such capabilities can be added on. In particular, [BBAutoComplete](http://c-command.com/bbautocomplete/) adds code completion features to TextWrangler. BBAutoComplete is free (donations accepted).

Disclosure: I have no connection to C-Command Software, but I did file a bug report that led to the release of the latest version of BBAutoComplete, and served as a volunteer beta tester. It's pretty amazing software.

Comment: That looks promising, but is there any way to make that run automatically (without having to press a key), like Xcode does?

Comment: Well, you could use Xcode instead of TextWrangler :-) Seriously, I doubt that can be done, and myself, I prefer the BBAC model to the Xcode model, but everyone has their own preferences. Why do you want to use TW and not XCode? I have my reasons for prefering TW, but it's because I like the way TW works. If you prefer another program, I'd recommend you use that program (especially if it's free).

Comment: I guess you are right, I just wanted to see if there's something else, because Xcode feels kind of sluggish at times (especially startup).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, TextWrangler is not capable of code completion. Bare Bones Software considers TextWrangler to be the free "little brother" to BBEdit. BBEdit features code completion as well as other more advanced features, but requires a purchase after the initial trial.

http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/comparison.html